# The strange BUG in CS GO on Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: steam

This happening while clicking TAB. Mouse or just crosshair is "jumping" in the random place. What is weird this happends even when TAB is not clicked just in random moment usually on the begining new round. I recorded video to show how it's look: https://youtu.be/dbgqPQ_7Rx8

Any ideas why it's happening? Please help me.

I found the solution.
The problem is going on when m_rawinput is set to 0, when it's set to 1, everything works fine.

Comment: If this only happens in CS:GO and not anywhere else, then this is a bug that you should report to CS:GO and/or Valve.

Comment: In the other topic where i posted this bug, the other people said that, they didn't experience same situations